# Fixed View above a List View within a Navigation View

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I get a fixed (not scrolling) view above a List view within a NavigationView in SwiftUI?

[image]
[image]

The first picture shows what I try to achive / have so far. However the second picture shos what happens if I pull down, the title slides above the fixed content.

Using offset on the List and a ZStack I got close but the NavigationView Title keeps scrolling above the fixed viewwhen pulling down on the list.

Although I thought this is a more general question, to not risk this question gets closed, here is the code I have:

```
    NavigationView {
    
    ZStack{
        List {
            /* .. */
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .offset(x: 0, y: showFilter ? 100 : 0)
        
        if showFilter {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Button")
                    })
                    .padding(5)
                    .background(Color(red: 238/255, green: 238/255, blue: 239/255))
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    .padding()
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
        Button(action: {
            // initial
            self.showFilter.toggle()
            
            // completely different, odd behaviour (navigation title never fades away)
            // withAnimation{ self.showFilter.toggle() }
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3.decrease.circle")
        }
    )
    .navigationBarTitle("List")
}
```

Comment: Would you show your code to be fixed otherwise you might get not what you expect?

Comment: I added my code above and twi images showing the desired result and the issue when pulling down. I think this issue is not so much related to the code I have atm, isn't this considered something more general? I thought that m,ight be sth. basic but instead it seems to mess a lot with the list and the navigation bar.

Comment: Also if you try it yourself, note, that when adding a withAnimation around the showFilter state property, the behaviour completely changes. In that case, scrolling will only take place within th elist view, the navigation title will not shrink anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offset is weak approach here, because user will not see last rows in list when filter is shown and there are items more than screen area.

You can consider variant with section as placeholder (it is sticky and not overlapped by header) for filter (maybe with some custom style for buttons), so simple demo based on your code snapshot is like below.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo1] [image: demo2]

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        Section(header: Group {
            if showFilter {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Button")
                        })
                        .padding(5)
                        .background(Color(red: 238/255, green: 238/255, blue: 239/255))
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .padding()
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }) {
            ForEach(0..<20) { i in
                Text("Item \(i)")
            }
        }}
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

Comment: That is creative! The sticky behaviour is perfect but it breaks when adding withAnimation to the showFilter property. The entir elist is animated to fade out to the right side. Is there a way to prevent that? It feels like it's messing with swiftUI and thus animation support gets wired. Or is it simply nut supported at this early age and workarounds are the best compromise?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your problem, can you please share a gif/video of the problem in action?

Either way you can try putting the list and the fixed view inside the same ZStack, put the list **before** the fixed view and give the fixed view a position attribute.

If the ZStack is inside the NavigationView it shouldn't affect the fixed view.

The Sudo-code would, roughly, be like this -

```
NavigationView {
   ZStack {
      List ...
 
      FixedView()
        .position(x: 100, y: 100)
   }
}
```

If this was not enough you can check out Paul Hudson's tutorial on Absolute Positioning [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/absolute-positioning-for-swiftui-views).

And for more help please post your code and give us a video/gif demonstration so we can understand your problem and test it beforehand :)

Comment: Thats basically what I aproached, but won't this cover the List's contents?

Comment: No I mean, the list starts below and I think my troubles are caused by setting an offset to the List view. Also I've the issue with the navigation title going over the fixed view which also makes the whole thing way to hacky imo.